# Integration(Improper Integration)

Tags: calculus

$$
\mbox{Integrate}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}
{\left(x + 2\right)\left(x^{2} + 1\right)}.
$$

My answer is infinity, because:

$$
\frac{1}{5}\,\ln\left(b + 2\right)-
\frac{1}{10}\,\left(b^{2} + 1\right) +
\frac{2}{5\arctan\left(b\right)} -
\frac{1}{5}\,\ln\left(2\right)
$$
when $b$ gets close to infinity. Is this correct $?$.

Comment: The integral is finite. There is a mistake in the antiderivative, you need a $\ln(b^2+1)$, not a $b^2+1$.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help on typesetting.

Comment: so are you saying that my integratin

Comment: so are you saying that there is a calculation mistake? I double checked it after seeing your comment But I can't find it

Comment: Oh I got it!! is it? pi/5-1/5*(ln(2))

Comment: @user255410 $\frac{1}{5} (\pi - \ln(2))$ is what I got too.

Comment: I would note that you might suspect something was wrong since the integrand is continuous over $ \ [ \ 0, \ \infty \ ) \ $ and the degree of the polynomial in the denominator is $ \ 3 \ $ . So this is a "Type-I" improper integral which passes the "$ p- $ test" and therefore should be convergent.

Answer (score 5):

Admitting that $$I=\int \frac{dx}{(x+2) \left(x^2+1\right)}$$ I suppose that you started with partial fraction decomposition and obtained $$\frac{1}{(x+2) \left(x^2+1\right)}=\frac 15\Big(\frac{2-x}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{x+2}\Big)=\frac 25 \frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac 1{10}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}+\frac 15\frac{1}{x+2}$$ So, integrating $$I=\frac 25 \tan^{-1}(x)-\frac 1{10}\log(x^2+1)+\frac 15\log(x+2)$$ $$I=\frac 25 \tan^{-1}(x)-\frac 1{10}\log(x^2+1)+\frac 1{10}\log((x+2)^2)=\frac 25 \tan^{-1}(x)+\frac{1}{10} \log \left(\frac{(x+2)^2}{x^2+1}\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Could you tell me how you obtained the partial fractions? I only learnt to decompose partial fractions when each term in the fraction has the same degree of $x$. This seems like a useful trick.

Comment: Well, you will learn it very soon $$\frac{1}{(ax+b) \left(cx^2+dx+e\right)}=\frac{A}{ax+b}+\frac{B+C x}{cx^2+dx+e}$$ just because the second term is quadratic.

Comment: Aha.... That's good to know. And then to find the values of A,B and C I basically solve the fraction on the right and equate it to the one on the left. Or is there an easier way?...

Comment: @Gummybears  For example, to find $A$, multiply both sides by $ax+b$ and let $x\to -b/a$.  That is easy.

Comment: @Dr.MV Doesn't it work out to be the same thing in its essence? I mean I'll still have to obtain 3 equations and solve for 3 variables? Or am I missing your point somewhere.

Comment: @Gummybears For example, to find $A$, multiply both sides by $ax+b$ and let $x\to -b/a$.  That is easy.

Comment: Oh yes... @Dr.MV My fault. It is much easier. Thanks for the tip. That makes life much easier...

Answer (score 4):

There was a slip in finding an antiderivative, it should be
$$\frac{1}{5}\ln(x+2)-\frac{1}{10}\ln(x^2+1)+\frac{2}{5}\arctan x.$$
Evaluate this at $b$, like you did, and let $b\to\infty$. The somewhat challenging part is the first two terms, which we should rewrite as
$$\frac{1}{5}\ln\left(\frac{b+2}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}\right).\tag{1}$$
Note that $\frac{b+2}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}\to 1$ as $b\to\infty$, so (1) has limit $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, one may use the residue theorem.  Consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log{z}}{(z+2)(z^2+1)} $$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour of outer radius $R$ and inner radius $\epsilon$ about the positive real axis.  As $\epsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$, the contour integral becomes equal to

$$-i 2 \pi \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+2)(x^2+1)} $$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles $z=-2$, $z=-i$, and $z=i$.  Thus, we have

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+2)(x^2+1)} = -\frac{\log{2}+i \pi}{5} - \frac{i \pi/2}{(2+i) 2 i} - \frac{i 3 \pi/2}{(2-i)(-2 i)} = \frac{\pi-\log{2}}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little to André's answer (**EDIT**: and Claude's), there was an error in the antiderivative.

If one performs a partial fraction decomposition on the integral we obtain:

$\begin{align}
\int \frac{2-x}{5(x^2+1)} + \frac{1}{5(x+2)} \hspace{.1cm} dx \\
\end{align}$

Then messing around with some nasty stuff inside (I used integration tables for assistance, but it's possible to do by hand) we obtain the following as our antiderivative:

$\begin{align}
\frac{2\arctan(x)-\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2}}{5} + \frac{\ln(x+2)}{5} \\
\end{align}$

Now in order to avoid domain errors we need to evaluate the antiderivative at $x$, as $x$ approaches $0^+$ and as $x$ approaches $\infty$.

$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{2\arctan(x)-\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2}}{5} + \frac{\ln(x+2)}{5} &= \frac{\ln(2)}{5} \\
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2\arctan(x)-\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2}}{5} + \frac{\ln(x+2)}{5} &= \frac{\pi}{5}
\end{align} $

Thus we find our (finite) answer of:

$\frac{\pi-\ln(2)}{5} $

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Hereafter, $\ds{\large\ln}$ is its *Principal Branch-Cut*.
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x
\over \pars{x + 2}\pars{x^{2} + 1}}} =
-\,\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x
\over \pars{x + 2}\pars{x + \ic}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{%
{1 \over x + 2} - {1 \over x + \ic}}{1 \over \ic - 2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 5}\,\Im\bracks{\pars{2 + \ic}
\ln\pars{x + 2 \over x + \ic}}_{\,0}^{\,\to\ \infty} =
{1 \over 5}\,\Im\bracks{\pars{2 + \ic}
\ln\pars{\ic \over 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 5}\,\Im\braces{\pars{2 + \ic}
\bracks{-\ln\pars{2} + {\pi \over 2}\,\ic}} =
\bbx{\pi - \ln\pars{2} \over 5} \approx 0.4897 \\ &
\end{align}